# Treatment effect table in R with horizontally-oriented variables

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, gtsummary

So i subsetted a dataframe to keep only my 4 columns of interest. I want to count the number of control (0) and treated (1) observations. I computed something with the gtsummary package, but the variables are vertically oriented (like here http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_summary.html), one below each other, and this is not what i want. I searched on google but all the tables i saw have this orientation too.

I put here a picture of what i'd like to obtain, if some of you have any idea !

[image: Desired output]

*code i use to obtain my initial table (same as in the link)*

```
install.packages("gtsummary")
library(gtsummary)

trial <- finaldf %>% select(treatment, 2digID,4digID,classificationsdescription)
trial %>% tbl_summary()

t2 <- trial %>% tbl_summary(by = treatment)
```

I cannot put the real data but i created an example that looks like my data :

```
_2ID <- c(38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80)
_4ID <- c(3837,3837,3837,3812,3812,3896,3894,3894,3877,3877, 8099,8099,8027,8027,8027,8033,8033,8064,8064,8022)
descriptions <- c('ILL1','ILL1','ILL1', 'ILL2','ILL2','ILL3','ILL4','ILL4','ILL5','ILL5','ILL1','ILL1','ILL2','ILL2','ILL2','ILL3','ILL3','ILL4','ILL4','ILL5')
trt <-c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0)

df.data <- data.frame(_2ID,_4ID,descriptions, trt)
```

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

I think i managed to solve this problem even if my output is a dataframe and not a "publication-ready" table :

```
install.packages("reshape2")
library(reshape2)

data_wide <- dcast(df,_2digID+_4digID+descriptions ~ treatment, value.var="counts")
```

But i'm not sure yet that this gives the right numbers tho.

Comment: Are you intending us to use one of the sample datasets in that article? What code you used to get this far?

Comment: @r2evans i'm gonna edit my post with the code (is the same than the one in the link i put), but i'm not allowed to put an example due to confidential issues i'm sorry. It was more to know if some of you already tried to obtain this kind of table (maybe group_by ?) i'm new to R so i'm still struggling

Comment: Sure, I understand data problems. You are a lot more likely to get involvement when you control the data and provide clarity on the expected output given that sample data. Thanks.

Comment: @r2evans i'll create a reproducible example with invented data that look like mine, give me a minute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below gets you *close*, but not exactly what you're after. I like the idea of being able to support tables like this, and I'll add it to the list of features to implement!

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #Uighur
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.1'

tbl <-
  trial %>%
  mutate(
    grade = paste("Grade", as.character(grade)),
    stage = paste("Stage", as.character(stage))
  ) %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = c(stage, grade),
    ~ .x %>%
      tbl_summary(by = trt, 
                  include = response,
                  type = response ~ "categorical",
                  missing = "no",
                  statistic = response ~ "{n}") %>%
      modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**"),
    .combine_with = "tbl_stack"
  ) %>%
  as_flex_table()
```

[image]

- Table truncated because it was very long!

<sup>Created on 2021-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi @daniel, thanks a lot for this update, it's amazing ! This is indeed what is the closest from what i was looking for as a publication-ready design !